# Nested queries in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I watched [Advanced patterns for GitHub's GraphQL API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5pIszu9MeM) by Rea Loretta on Youtube and i saw the below code (at [08:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5pIszu9MeM&t=491s))

```
{
  organization(loqin:"toast-ninja") {
   repositories( first: 100) {
    nodes {
     name
     pullRequests(first: 100) {
      nodes { number title }
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Is this call a nested query and how can i achieve this in nodejs + typegraqhql + apollo server express ?
I've only been working with graphql for 1 month and sorry for any mistakes in this post

Comment: Why did you NIET share a link to the youtube ?

Comment: sorry for my late reply. Here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5pIszu9MeM&t=491s (8:20)